# auto increment multiplication in Javascript

Tags: javascript

No idea why this Javascript snippet won't auto increment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 1;
var newCount=count*2;
do {

    count*2 = newCount;

while (newCount < 25){
    alert ("New Count is" +  newcount);}

</script>
```

Looking to have alert windows with the new count up to 25.

Thanks

Comment: Are the syntax errors in your actual code?

Comment: There a few errors here: 1) `count*2 = newCount` doesn't make sense, 2) that's not how a `do-while` works, it should be `do{ ... } while(...);` 3) `newCount` is being (would be) set to the *same* value over and over.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors. For example, missing the `}` that closes the `do` block and unnecessary `{` and `}` wrapping the alert statement. Also, the assignment in the do block is invalid since the operation should be on the right side, not the left. In order to help, can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your variable assignment is backward in your `do` statement and that you are missing a closing brace. Also, the `alert` should be inside the `do` statement so that it will alert each time it loops, up to your condition.

```js
var count = 1;
var newCount = count;
do {
  newCount = newCount * 2;
  alert("New Count is " + newCount);

} while (newCount < 25);
```

Comment: That's still not going to give the desired behaviour, as newCount is going to remain the same with each iteration. Plus you have `newcount` instead of `newCount` in your alert

Comment: @StephenTG You are right. I misread the question, and updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have syntax errors in your code.  `do...while` is not two separate calls.  Also, your assignment operator is backwards.

Try replacing your `do...while` loop with this:

```
do {
    newCount = newCount * 2;
    alert ("New Count is " +  newCount);
} while (newCount < 25)
```

I'd also like to note that since the `count` variable is never changed, the `newCount` variable will always be the result of `1 * 2`, and this will result in an infinite loop.  My answer changes the looping assignment to use the `newCount` value instead of `count` in its calculation.